# Defining a Equality relationship when it already exists? I'm going crazy

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, equivalence-relations

> (Equality Relation) There is one familiar relation between a set and itself that we consider every set $S$ mentioned in this text to possess: namely, the equality relation $=$ defined on a set $S$ by
>
> $=$ is the subset $\{(x, x) \mid x \in S\}$ of $S \times S$.
>
> Thus for any $x\in S$, we have $x = x$, but if $x$ and $y$ are different elements of $S$, then $(x,y) \not \in =$ and we write $x \ne y$.

The paragraph above is from the book of algebra by Fraleigh.

I'm really confused here. If you look at the phrase "but if $x$ and $y$ are different elements of $S$," it seems that there is already a equality relationship in the set $S$.

By the way, can we define $=$ again?

Is $=$ the symbol that I used to use here?

Comment: The phrase "but if $x$ and $y$ are different elements of $S$," is not part of the definition of $=$, but is describing the fact that from the way we define the tight apartness relation $\not =$ as the set $(X \times X) \setminus =$, it follows that $\neg(x = y) \longleftrightarrow x \not = y$.

Answer (score 1):

You could think of "$x,y$ different elements" as meaning $(x,y) \not \in =$.

We define the relation $=$ on $S$, and this gives two further (implicit) definitions:

- $x,y$ are the "same" element, if $(x,y) \in =$
- $x,y$ are "different" elements, if $(x,y) \not \in =$

from which we get the answer to your question.

As far as "can I define $=$ again", sure, but you want it to be defined in such a way that encapsulates the given definition. There can be multiple distinct but equivalent definitions of an entity in math.

And yes, $=$ is the desired symbol -- this is how we formally codify what it means for two things to be equal.

Comment: thanks for Answer.  but I have to point out somthing.  "if x and y are different elements of S, then (x,y)∉="  this statement is not "if and only if".  This means that we already know what things are the same and different before we define  equality relationships. And it's like a contradiction.

Comment: How can you make this set {(x,x)∣x∈S} before you define what is the same and what is different?

Comment: "This means that we already know what things are the same and different before we define equality relationships." We are defining same and different ***after*** we define equality. If equality relations are definition $1$, then "same" and "different" are definition $2$.

Comment: "How can you make this set {(x,x)∣x∈S} before you define what is the same and what is different?" Why would you not be able to?

Comment: But the author is already using the word different To define the equality relationship. If a and b are elements of the set S, how can we know whether (a, b) belongs to the set = or not? You will need to know whether a and b are the same or different. Doesn't that mean you know what's the same and what's different?

Comment: The word "different" is not being used in the definition of $=$. The definition of equality (on $S$) is simply the subset of $S \times S$ given by $\{ (x,x) \mid x \in S\}$. What "different" and "same" means are coming thereafter.

Comment: Let's say we have a set S with five elements. And let's say that this set doesn't have the notion of being same or different.
However, having five elements means that there is a one-to-one function f:{1,2,3,4,5} => S. And since it is inductive, f(1) and f(2) are different. This means that 'equality' already exists in the set S(first defined), and 'equality relation' seems to be another concept that just uses the same symbol '='. For example, when defining the equality of a tuple or matrix, the equality is not defined in the same way as above.

Comment: Who's to say you have $S$ without an equality relation, then, if you somehow know it has five elements? If you know it has some distinct number of elements, that pre-supposes you *already* have the equality relation.

Comment: that's what I mean. Any kind of equality exists before defining the equality relationship, which means that the terms "same" and "different" can already be used. Are you arguing that you cannot use the word 'same' before defining the quality relation written in my question? I don't think I can communicate well with you.

Comment: For example, natural numbers already have concepts of equal and different. On top of that, isn't there just a equality relationship as a subset of N * N?